# The English translation for the Chinese word "剩女", meaning an unmarried girl over 27 without a boyfriend

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, translation, chinese

The Chinese word "剩女" means "an unmarried girl over 27 without a boyfriend". Since better girls are already in love or married, some girls are left and it seems that no men are interested in them. The word has a negative meaning. A TV station in China translates the word into "leftover woman". I searched some English corpora and the data show clearly that the adjective 'leftover' is invariably collocated with food. So I think "leftover woman" is a miscollocation.

Do native speakers understand the meaning  of "leftover woman" if it is used at all? Is it offensive?

I want to use the word "spinster", but it is a negative word. "Single" is unsuitable here because its meaning is too broad. What is the best neutral word or phrase for that meaning?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118827/discussion-on-question-by-anshan-today-the-english-translation-for-the-chinese-w).

Comment: We need to know more. Is this for use in a novel? a newspaper article? an academic treatise?  How often will you use the term in the text?  Please give a sample sentence that shows how you want to use the phrase.

Comment: Note: Please study the details of the *single-word* tag, it says, *"This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.  Click on "Info" or "View Tag" and "Learn more ..." for more information. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word."*

Answer (score 26):

There is not going to be an ideal fit for a *neutral* version of this term in English. Traditionally, older unmarried women were looked upon negatively So you have older words like *spinster* and *old maid* that have strongly negative connotations. There are also adjectives like *unmarried* and *unattached* that may come across as negative due to the *un-* form.

It is only in the last few generations that women living independent and unmarried lives has been widely regarded as neutral, let alone positive, so there are relatively few terms for them. Some collocations (like *single woman*) are technically fitting, though they don't pertain to a single age. *Bachelorette* might have fit at one time, though many English speakers will associate that word with the TV show *[The Bachelorette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bachelorette)*, which features a woman being taken on dates by a number of competing eligible men. So the neutral options don't exactly fit either.

So if you are translating the term, you may need to decide whether an English translation is sufficient or whether you need to translate literally and gloss the concept, a practice common in academia ([JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/action/doBasicSearch?Query=leftover%20woman)) but less common in other contexts.

Comment: Within the academic fields of Chinese Studies/Asian Studies, "leftover women" is *the* term for this. Maybe you can come up with a more polite term...but the concept itself does exist as a widespread social issue in China, and that is the term scholars actually use, so no need to create another.

Comment: @Village 'Within the academic fields of Chinese Studies/Asian Studies ...' almost certainly implies that the terminology is not sufficiently standardised to be on-topic on ELU. Probably, most native speakers encountering the string 'leftover women' for the first time would treat it as a nonce term, meaning possibly wallflowers at a student party, and be worried about the propriety of the choice of words.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since Chinese demographics are of interest (and economic consequence) around the world, it’s likely that this issue will arise sooner rather than later. Given the one-child Chinese policy, only recently changed, there will also be a time of “leftover” men.

Comment: @Xanne Until such time, off-topic on ELU.

Comment: In Greek there is a similar term:
* https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/γεροντοκόρη
* https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/γεροντοκόρη

Comment: It wasn't offensive in the past.

Comment: @tdgs And Japan has "Christmas cake" (the implication being that you've been "left on the shelf", and no-one will want you now).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: A *question* just about technical academic usage could be off-topic here.  But it’s very reasonable for *answers* to consider/discuss technical usage, although they should certainly also acknowledge how broadly the technical usage is used or understood.

Comment: Is *spinster* really more negative than the original Chinese word given?  It’s negative just insofar as such women were/are viewed negatively, and talking about such women as a group usually suggests endorsement of that viewpoint.  But the word itself doesn’t add further negative connotations beyond the use of the category, so in that sense it’s a neutral word (unlike, say, sexist or ethnic slurs).  My impression from OP’s explanation is that this is fairly similar to the ways in which the Chinese word is negative/neutral.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, "leftover woman" is the correct translation.

It may not be politically correct, or seem polite, but that is the term and it reflects Chinese cultural attitudes towards those women within Mainland China.

The word is used in China and in English-language literature on the subject, including in many peer-review journal articles. See [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C32&q=leftover%20women&btnG=), for example.

Outsiders to China will not likely know the meaning, so depending on your readers, an explanation must be given.

Comment: leftover woman has no meaning in English

Comment: I'm afraid that 'Outsiders to China will not likely know the meaning' almost certainly makes this too niche for ELU. Perhaps better on Linguistics, which considers language overlaps.

Comment: @Strawberry no *defined* meaning, no, but the phrase certainly makes sense; a woman who’s been leftover.

Comment: @Fivesideddice - Leftover from what? Picking teams in dodgeball?

Comment: This seems an appropriate answer for some contexts, though not for all.  Most native-speakers won’t be familiar with it and would require a little explanation to understand it, so it can’t just be used in isolation.  But it’s reasonably widely used in e.g. journalism on the topic, not only in academic literature.  For any context where the extra precision is worth giving a few words of explanation, this is an excellent answer.

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean it has no meaning? If a phrase is used a certain way, it certainly has meaning - and it it objectively used in a certain way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheng_nu?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @Tim No doubt, the prhrase Sheng Nu has a meaning in Chinese. The phrase 'leftover woman' has no meaning in English - or at least it's meaning would be ambiguous.  If someone says "oh, she's a leftover woman", an English-speaking monoglot will simply respond "What do you mean?"

Comment: @Strawberry once again, just because many people do not know it’s meaning doesn’t mean it doesn’t have one. You might not know the meaning of “peng”, but it still has a clear definition.

Comment: @Tim: Just because the meaning of a certain phrase can be inferred from context, that doesn't mean there has to be any meaning attached to it in the first place. And even I as a non-native speaker can tell you with absolute confidence, that basically nobody would, upon hearing the phrase "leftover woman" out of context, think to themselves "Ah, that must mean someone who's in her late twenties and single". Nobody.

Comment: @Peter and nobody who hears “peng” would ever think that means attractive. You’re just describing how words work - that you need to know what their meaning is to understand them. Just because you need to learn the meaning, doesn’t mean it doesn’t have one.

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, "leftover" doesn't unambiguously refer to food as in "last night's leftovers in the fridge".

A leftover anything is something that remains. For instance, "Bob went into the building one more time to grab a few leftover boxes and items, and then shut the door for good."

If the "leftover" is turned into a noun, and particularly if subsequently pluralized to "leftovers", then it has a stronger association with food: that word refers to uneaten food more often than not.

Outside of any context, "leftover woman" will not be unambiguously interpreted as an unmarried older woman. It could be a woman left behind in any conceivable situation: "Everyone was rescued from the island, except for one leftover woman."

But in a discussion about unmarried women, if the term is introduced, it will be clear what it refers to; and it will have a negative connotation, laced with sexism, possibly deeply offensive to some people. It has the interpretation of insinuating that a woman is just an item, and one without a husband is just an uncollected or unconsumed item.

> "I want to use the word "spinster", but it is a negative word."

But you started this discussion with a negative Chinese word. If that Chinese word has connotations that a woman is just an item, and an unmarried one is just a wasted, unconsumed item, then "leftover woman" actually works. If it doesn't have connotations which are that bad, then "old maid" and such may be more appropriate.

In any case, the job of a translator isn't to produce a sugar-coated version of a text in another language.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a "passed-over" woman, which puts focus on the actions of others, rather than suggesting a deficiency as "left-over" seems to.

Comment: I think this is an interesting suggestion. This could be a really good answer with more explanation of why "passed-over" might be a good choice.

Comment: Our site is a bit different from other Q&As, as we emphasise the importance of *authoritative* answers backed up by *evidence* (preferably, a linked reference). So I would regard @ColleenV's helpful suggestion as a strong recommendation: please [edit] your post to add "more explanation of why *passed-over* might be a good choice." For further guidance, read [answer]. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much fev, ColleenV and @Chappo Hasn't Forgotten Monica (very interesting to read about how you chose your moniker, although it chose you, didn't it?).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by TaliesinMerlin, In English we have the (somewhat dated) term "old maid"...

> **old maid** NOUN
> 1 *derogatory* A single woman regarded as too old for marriage.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/old_maid)

Comment: I don’t think 27 is old enough for an “old maid”. A woman can be single and without a partner without being too old for anyone to want to marry.

Comment: The question specifically says they don't want a word with negative connotations, so "derogatory" makes this a non-starter. And I don't think I've heard this term outside of period pieces for decades.

Comment: @ColleenV a hundred years ago an unmarried woman of 25 was considered an old maid, past her prime with little chance of a good marriage.  See for example https://www.newspapers.com/clip/13853547/mary-anne-barry-taken-to-asylum-after/ and https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/a/constance-wilcox-pignatelli/such-ways-are-dangerous/

Comment: @arp A lot of things were different 100 years ago. I don’t see how that’s relevant to a request for a modern English word.

Comment: As the answer says, 'old maid' is a dated term; when it *was* in common use, it would certainly have been used for an unmarried and unpromised woman of 27.

Comment: @arp But the author is presumably looking for a term that applies today. Saying “here’s a word that applied a hundred years ago” isn’t that helpful, although it might be an interesting aside.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct match, but if she has her own job and life, "career woman" or "career-minded woman" or "single professional woman" might fit.

This is specific to the woman who puts more of her life into her job, and so her single state is her choice, or the result of her being busy,  rather than because she is left over. Unlike spinster or old maid (both a bit Jane Austen!) it's not a negative term.

EDIT: The new answer from @aliental seems to support this, and we might add "independent woman" to the choices above, since this does seem to be an official term for a woman making these lifestyle choices. Of course, some career women also have boyfriends, so it's still not a perfect fit.

Answer (score 0):

[ Sheng nu ](it's three words not one!) seems to be a joke rhyme of 剩余 [ shèng yú ], so if it were possible to find a rhyming chide, that would be a good translation. perhaps like a "debris dame", "Lady Leftover". "waste woman". "female fragments" I can't think of a very good one.